# Remote debugging Azure Functions symbols not found

Tags: azure, remote-debugging, azure-functions

I'm trying to remote debug an azure function. So I followed the youtube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uiqc0iWwAzw&t=17m10s
But when I attach the debugger (to w3wp.exe) the breakpoint will never be hit.

The breakpoint has an open circle and states: "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

```
'w3wp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/1060585570/ROOT-1-131176201993551687): Loaded 'ƒ-HttpTriggerCSharp1#ℛ*5465853b-4ded-4374-bb31-e99c9fc6cc71#1-0'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'w3wp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/1060585570/ROOT-1-131176201993551687): Loaded 'ScriptHost'. 
'w3wp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/1060585570/ROOT-1-131176201993551687): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'.
```

I found a similar issue: 
[Remote debugging Azure website: Breakpoints not hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511928/remote-debugging-azure-website-breakpoints-not-hit)

I also disable the "Enable Just my Code" option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to disabling "Enable just my code", please also make sure the setting (in the same dialog) "Require source files to exactly match the original version" is disabled as well.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately I still have the same "symbols not found" error

Comment: This fixed my error with symbols not being found, but still not hitting breakpoints, tho,

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem - the following github issue speaks to it, but solution didn't solve my problem:

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/872

I finally stumbled across the answer here:

http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Remote-Debugging-Azure-Functions-V2-The-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-No-symbols-have-been-loaded-for-this-document

It boils down to manually attaching to the process in Azure, rather than relying on the Cloud Explorer right-click functionality.